# Emulating clicks behind form

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, pixel

**This post is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**.

I just have a couple of questions for you. I want to enumerate every pixel in a bitmap that is displayed using the BackgroundImage property of my form, and then I want to emulate a click behind the form if the current pixel is black. So, how should/can I do it?

For example (here's some pseudocode):

```
For Each P As Pixel In Form1.BackgroundImage
    If P.Color = Color.Black Then
        EmulateClickBehindForm(P.Position)
    End If
Next
```

My form currently looks like this:

[image]

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
For Each P As Pixel In Form1.BackgroundImage
    If P.Color = Color.Black Then
        Dim sender As Object = Me
        Dim e As New MouseEventArgs(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 1, P.Position.X, P.Position.Y, 0)
        Form_Click(sender, e)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Except I'd need real Visual Basic code or a real idea of how I should be doing it and not pseudocode. The reason I provided it was to explain better to those who program. Besides, it's not my form that should be clicked, it's the window behind/underneath it.

Comment: To be able to send **mouse** events to _whatever_ is behind your form you will need to rely on WinAPI calls and hooks to capture what the mouse is doing on and away of your form. This is not a trivial thing to do; trust me, I've done it and it's not easy. If you could better explain what you want to do _we_ might be able to provide some more appropriate information.

Comment: I want to redraw all black pixels on the surface behind the form.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this like so:

```
        Dim Bmp As New Bitmap(Me.BackgroundImage)
        Dim Pos As New Point(Me.Location)
        Dim BmpSize As New Bitmap(Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        For y As Integer = 0 To BmpSize.Height - 1
            For x = 0 To BmpSize.Width - 1
                Dim curPixColor As Color = Bmp.GetPixel(x, y)
                If curPixColor = Color.White Then Continue For
                If IsColorBlack(curPixColor) Then
                    Dim pre = New Point(Pos.X + x, Pos.Y + y)
                    SetCursorPos(pre.X, pre.Y)
                    Application.DoEvents()
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Some explanation:

I enumerate the pixels in the backgroundimage, for each pixel that resembles the color black, I make the mouse click on the screen, at the position of the form + the position of the pixel.

It's quite simple really, here's some pseudocode to shine some light on the process:

```
For each P As Pixel In Form1.BackgroundImage
    If P.Color = Color.Black Then
        Click(Form1.Location.X + P.Location.X, Form1.Location.Y + P.Location.Y)
    End If
Next
```